# Should each website have a different MySQL user for a single database?

Tags: mysql

If I have multiple websites that access the same MySQL database - should each website use a different MySQL user, or is it ok to use the same user for all of the website?

The database and websites are on the same server.

Are there any pros or cons for each configuration?

Comment: depends if its your server or a hosted server as the features and settings can differ greatly

Comment: Typically, a user in this sense is simply a 'user type', so administrator, editor, and guest, for instance. So that's 3 users

Comment: If your website has some kind vulnerability that allows attackers to execute database queries (like [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), would you like them to have access to all the databases or just the one of the website that is vulnerable? I would definitely separate them and only give those users permission to access data for the database they should have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends if you're the only one that's accessing the database, and what kind of website it is. If you're making websites for clients with WordPress for example, or any other CMS where the database credentials are saved in an accessible file (like wp-config), you definitely want to have different databases.

In case you're the only one accessing the database and the websites are all your own, I guess you could use the same user. I think I'd use different ones, even if it's just for clarity, but there is something to say for having just one account regarding security. Having just one account with a strong password means there are less accounts that could get hacked.